# How to trim a field in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, trim

I have a table with eMail-Addresses (e.g. "peter.test@example.com") and I want to trim the Address to receive the name and domain.

```
select LTRIM(Addressfield, '@') AS NAME from table
```

But the result is exact the same as in the table field and I would expect "peter.test"

Comment: You have confused terms. That's not [trimming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(programming)) but [substringing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `regexp_substr()` function can be used to get the desired output:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('peter.test@example.com','[^@]+') as "NAME" 
  from dual
```

Comment: I would expect "peter.test".

Comment: "select REGEXP_SUBSTR('peter.test@example.com','[^@]+') as "NAME" from dual;"